# Put to trouble or put through trouble?

Tags: grammaticality

"Sorry for putting you **to** so much trouble"

"Sorry for putting you **through** so much trouble"

Some sites on the internet say it's put sbd to trouble and some say it's put sbd through trouble. Are both right? Is the first sentence grammatical?

Answer (score 1):

They're both fine to me (British English).

**Through** is something you'd say when someone has had to deal with problems or a tough situation, and eventually they got *through* it. You could say it to someone after they've finished, or while they're working through it (in the sense of "sorry you're going through this").

If you put someone **to** trouble, it's more about effort, or imposition - you're giving them work to do, which isn't necessarily a problem, but you want to apologise for bothering them. It's in the same sense as "sorry to trouble you" when you need a moment of their time.

Someone can also *go to the trouble* of doing something - it usually means they made the effort, they took their time to do something. It doesn't imply any actual problems in the same way as "going *through* trouble" does.

Answer (score -1):

> Sorry for putting you **to** so much trouble.

***put someone to*** - To cause someone to enter into a certain state or condition. In this usage, a noun or pronoun can be used between "put" and "to."

[put someone to - definitions](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+someone+to)

According to this definition, "to" can be used to express the sentence. But I would rather use a sentence like:

> Sorry for putting you **in** so much trouble.

However, from this [site](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+someone+in), I could not find any particular definition that suits this case. But I am positive I have heard people using this sentence.

> Sorry for putting you **through** so much trouble.

This sentence is idiomatically and grammatically correct. The perfect one to use in every case. [put someone through](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+someone+through)

Comment: This is just wrong. You can't "put someone in trouble"; you can "get someone in trouble", but that means something completely different. And as cactsustictacs points out, "to" and "through" mean different things as well; through is not "perfect to use in every case".